# How to combine two mySQL queries when LEFT JOIN is further to be restricted by date range

Tags: mysql

I have two mySQL tables, customers and invoices. The both tables have customer account number that are used to link them together.

The invoices table have also a date of the invoice amonst the other data.

What I am trying to query is: "customers that have not been invoiced in certain time range"

If I exclude the time range then I can get the list of customers that have not been invoiced any time using LEFT JOIN i.e.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.account, t1.name
  FROM customer AS t1 LEFT JOIN
       customer_invoices AS t2 ON t1.account = t2.account
 WHERE t2.account IS NULL
```

Now I would like to combine this with query so that the LEFT JOIN would only be using customer_invoices within certain period. I.e. I would like to combine the above query with

```
SELECT *
  FROM customer_invoices as t2
 WHERE t2.date >= '2017/01/01' AND t2.date <=  '2017/12/31'
```

I have tried UNIONS or adding `AND t2.date >= '2017/01/01' AND t2.date <=  '2017/12/31'` to the end of the LEF JOIN query with no luck.

I was hoping that I could somehow execute first the second query that selects the data within certain time range, and then use the result as a part of the LEFT JOIN query, but not have managed to find a way yet. Perhaps someone could help? Thank you very much.

Comment: "adding `AND t2.date >= '2017/01/01' AND t2.date <=  '2017/12/31'` to the end of the LEF JOIN query" - IMHO that should work. Please add sample data and expected result, so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Did not work, hence query. But both tricot and scaisEdge answers work well.

Comment: As I wrote, you should post sample data that will reproduce your issue. Because it works here: http://rextester.com/STKSI16225

Answer (score 1):

you could use a not in clause for avoid the account that have invoice the time range you need

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.account, t1.name
  FROM customer AS t1 

  WHERE t1.account not in (
    select customer_invoices.account 
    from customer_invoices
    where date >= '2017/01/01' AND date <=  '2017/12/31'
  )
```

Comment: Thank you - this works the treat! SQL query time 0.3244 secs.

Comment: Why are you joining the `customer_invoices` table. You are not selecting anything from it. But the join may produce duplicates (which you are removing with `DISTINCT`).

Comment: @PaulSpiegel   thanks  .. correct  .. unuseful table removed

Answer (score 1):

When you would use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`, you could use the `HAVING` clause for this:

```
SELECT    t1.account, t1.name
FROM      customer AS t1
LEFT JOIN customer_invoices AS t2 ON t1.account = t2.account
GROUP BY  t1.account, t1.name
HAVING    COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.date BETWEEN '2017/01/01' AND '2017/12/31' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you - this work also ! My sql query time 4.86s for large data set. Really appreciated. Have a look also scaisEdge reply, this produces the same result in 1/10th of time.